# Calculating Running Balances

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014, cumulative-sum

I am struggling with how to calculate a running balance that is dynamic. Here's what I have.

- A range of periods with an intersection between total duration and each month in the duration.
- A rate that is applied at each intersection.
- An initial amount
- A need to calculate a running balance based on the initial amount less the rate applied in that period.

For example, I have a project worth $2,500,000 that is 8 months long. The rates for each interval are as follows: 1. 8.10% 2. 14.04% 3. 26.8% 4. 29.1% 5. 33.4% 6. 30.4% 7. 47.4% 8. 100%

For period 1 I have $202,500 (8.10% × $2.5 million), For period 2, I have $322,500 (14.04% × $2,297,500 ($2.5 - $202,500)), for period 3, I have $530,000 (26.8% × $1,974,999 ($2.5 - sum of first two periods ($525,000)). At the end of period 8, my balance is $0 and my earned amount = $2.5 million.

Can I use something like `RunningTotal = Sum(MonthlyAmts) OVER (ORDER BY XX ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING), ORDER BY Period`? Or is this a candidate for a cursor?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give us sample data?

Comment: Amount is $2,500,000. The duration is 8 months. The rates are 8.1% for period 1, 14.4% for period 2, 26.8% for period 3, 29.1% for period 4, 33.4% for period 5, 30.4% for period 6, 47.4% for period 7, and 100% for period 8. In period 1, the amount "earned" is $202,500 which is $2,500,000 x 8.1%. In period 2, the amount is $322,500, which is $2,500,000 - $202,500 x 14.4%. In period 3, the amount is $530,000, which is $2,500,000 - (sum of amounts earned in periods 1 and 2) x 26.8%. This declining balance eventually reaches $0 and the amount earned reaches $2,500,000.

Comment: I meant, in the form of tables. And the expected outcome.

Comment: Length of project: 8 months, Amount = $2,500,000

Period   Rate            Amount             Balance
1       0.081         $202,500.00 $2,500,000.00
2 0.14036997 $322,500.01 $2,297,500.00
3 0.26835443 $530,000.00 $1,974,999.99
4 0.29065744 $420,000.00 $1,445,000.00
5 0.33414634 $342,500.00 $1,025,000.00
6 0.3040293 $207,500.00    $682,500.00
7 0.47368421 $225,000.00    $475,000.00
8 1                 $250,000.00    $250,000.00

Comment: I tried inputting this in a table format, but I do not know how it will render in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your table structure. But it sounds like you should use function. If you would like get all years use table valued function, if you are interested only on result use scalar function. Or better way with recursive CTE.